# Mongodb & Espress: store a object in a model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

i have this model:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        userName: {type: String, required: true},
        firstName: {type: String},
        lastName: {type: String},
        password: {type: String, required: true},
        rate: Number,
        rates: {type: Object, default: {String: String}},

    }
);
```

I just want to do a put and store the new key/valye in rates. First of all, I check if `rates` is correctly initialized and it is. Then when I do the put request I all my parameters in `console.log` and they exist and I print before and after the update as you can see.

```
 if (data.rate) {
    console.log(user.rates,' before')
    user.rates[data.rate_id] = data.rate
    console.log(user.rates,' update')

    user.rate = updateRate(user.rates)
 }
```

Now I don't care about `user.rate` but only about `user.RATES`, so the problem is the following:

first put, output:

```
{} ' before'
{ '5686e0b40a8c0bc90a4fb4cc': '4' } ' update'
```

Now in the next one, if I want to put '5' I expect:

```
{'5686e0b40a8c0bc90a4fb4cc': '4'} ' before'
{ '5686e0b40a8c0bc90a4fb4cc': '5' } ' update'
```

But i have this:

```
{} ' before'
{ '5686e0b40a8c0bc90a4fb4cc': '5' } ' update'
```

So my `user.rates` isn't stored. This is the code where i save it:

```
user.save();
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save the following Object: `{ ObjectId : String}` on a field in the schema that expects `{String : String}`.